# Arduino with DS18b20 and ENC28J60 to thingspeak

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, ethernet

Can anyone help me to make this work? I have been trying for a couple of days to make this work, but no luck. I use a DS18b20 Temperature sensor and an ENC28J60 Ethernet module. The last code that I find like close to work is:

```
/*
| Post temp. values from a DS18B20 to ThingSpeak using the Ethercard interface based on the 
| ENC28J60 chip.
| Based on the Ethercard example from www.jeelabs.org
| Phil Grant Jan 2014
*/
#include <EtherCard.h>
// change these settings to match your own setup
#define APIKEY  "xxxx"

//DHT Setup
//#include "DHT.h"
//#define DHTPIN 2     // what pin we're connected to
// Uncomment whatever type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)  
//DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
byte mymac[] = { 0x12,0x11,0x22,0x12,0x21,0x11 };
char website[] = "api.thingspeak.com";
byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
uint32_t timer;
Stash stash;

void setup () {
Serial.begin(57600);
//dht.begin(); //Initializate DHT
  Serial.println("\n[webClient]");
if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0) 
    Serial.println( "Failed to access Ethernet controller");
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
    Serial.println("DHCP failed");
  ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip);  
  ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip);  
  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
  ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop () {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 60000; //Transmit every minute
    delay(2000);  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  char h_buffer[10];
  String Hstring = dtostrf(h,0,5,h_buffer);
  //Convert Humidity value to String
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  //float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  char t_buffer[10];
  String Tstring = dtostrf(t,0,5,t_buffer);
  //Convert Temperature value to String
  byte sd = stash.create();
  stash.print("field1=");
  stash.println(Hstring);
  stash.print("&field2=");
  stash.println(Tstring);
  stash.save();
  // generate the header with payload - note that the stash size is used,
  // and that a "stash descriptor" is passed in as argument using "$H"
  Stash::prepare(PSTR(
    "POST /update HTTP/1.1" "\r\n"
    "Host: $F" "\r\n"
    "Connection: close" "\r\n"
    "X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: $F" "\r\n"
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "\r\n"
    "Content-Length: $D" "\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "$H"),
    website, PSTR(APIKEY), stash.size(), sd);
    // send the packet - this also releases all stash buffers once done
    ether.tcpSend();
  }
}
```

But on the serial monitor I get this message:

> ```
> [webClient]
> IP:  192.168.88.252
> GW:  192.168.88.1
> DNS: 8.8.8.8
> DNS failed
> SRV: 0.0.0.0
> ```

---

I have try all of this network configurations and I am sure that arduino have access to internet from my home router. I can ping arduino IP address from other computers in my network and all computers have access to Internet from same router and same subnet with same DNS.
Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> But on serial monitor I get msg: [webClient] IP: 192.168.88.252 GW: 192.168.88.1 DNS: 8.8.8.8 DNS failed SRV: 0.0.0.0

The line above shows that you have the Ethernet interface configured to use a private IP address (192.168.X.Y) and that you're trying to reach Google's DNS server at 8.8.8.8. That means that you've got to have a connection to the Internet accessible through your gateway (192.168.88.1). The gateway will have to be doing NAT since your router will not (should) not route traffic from private addresses to the Internet – and even if it did other routers would not be able to route traffic back to you.

The first thing to do is to confirm that you've got an Internet connection and that the address you're trying to reach exists. If you've got another computer on the same network that can reach the Internet try the address you're trying to reach (api.thingspeak.com) and confirm that the name resolves to an IP address. Then confirm that the gateway you're using on that machine matches what you've got configured on the Arduino.

Another good thing to check would be that the Arduino seems to be working on the wire. There are a number of ways that you could confirm this:

- Check to see that you can ping it.
- Check to see that it shows up in your ARP cache (use the command `arp -a` in the terminal if you're on Linux or OS X. You're looking to see that the IP address assigned to the Arduino is unique and that you get back the MAC address that you expect.
- Try pointing your DNS at your router (assuming it is configured to act as a DNS server). That will let you see if you get a response from inside your network. Before doing this configure that `api.thingspeak.com` resolves using ping or by going there on another machine. If this works, you should try it pointing another machine at 8.8.8.8 as your DNS server – just to confirm that this works. If it works and the Arduino fails then it is getting more puzzling.

At this point you most likely will have identified the problem. If you haven't it would make sense to spend some time learning a bit about `tcpdump` or Wire Shark so that you can watch TCP traffic on the network. At the very least you'll want to be able to watch to see the basic DNS transaction. One possibility may be that the Arduino expects the DNS server to be on the local wire and that it is timing out too fast.